# Javascript: How to remove lastChild among select statements

Tags: javascript

The below code I have is designed to create and remove a new dropdown menu upon clicking the button. However, when clicking the remove button, it removes the first created dropdown. How do I set it up to remove the last created dropdown?

```js
 document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',
  function(addioc){
   var addition = document.getElementById('IOC_select').cloneNode(true);
   document.getElementById('IOC_input').appendChild(addition);
  }
 );

 document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',
  function(removeioc){
   var subtraction = document.getElementById('IOC_select');
   subtraction.parentNode.removeChild(subtraction);
  } 
 )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
<form id="IOC_input">
 <select id = "IOC_select">
  <option value = "IOC"> IOC Type: </option> 
 </select>
</form>

<button id="add">ADD IOCs</button>
<button id="remove"> REMOVE IOCs</button>
<button id="submit"> SUBMIT IOCs</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited to add the HTML code that was asked for.

Comment: Could you show the related HTML (how is the remove button nested) ? Also ids have to be unique, `add` and `remove` should probably be classes.

Comment: Please provide a full example, e.g. additional html code.

Comment: FYI: the arguments being passed to your event callbacks are the event themselves. It would be a lot clearer to just name the arguments `event` to avoid confusion since the events are `click` and not *add* or *remove* anything.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('IOC_select');` will always return the first element with `id="IOC_select"`.
Remove the last element of the `subtraction.parentNode.children` Change the following part

```
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',
        function(removeioc){
            removeioc.preventDefault();
            var subtraction = document.getElementById('IOC_select');
            let children = subtraction.parentNode.children
            subtraction.parentNode.removeChild(children[children.length - 1]);
            return false;
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.querySelector()`, you can get a direct reference to the last `option` element by using the [`last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class and remove it:

Also, you don't need the lines about `.preventDefault()` since there is no default behavior associated with these events. You also don't need `return false` here.

```js
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var subtraction = document.querySelector('#IOC_select > option:last-child');
    // If there is an element to remmove
    if (subtraction){
      subtraction.parentNode.removeChild(subtraction);
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="IOC_select">
  <option>choice 1</option>
  <option>choice 2</option>
  <option>choice 3</option>
  <option>choice 4</option>
  <option>choice 5</option>
  <option>choice 6</option>  
  <option>choice 7</option>
  <option>choice 8</option>  
</select>
<button id="remove">Remove last choice</button>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove options, I want to remove the entire duplicated dropdown.